# Removal of bonded kettle element from kettle base using chemical methods

Tags: electrical, adhesive

I have asked the below question via [electronic SE site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520652/replacing-kettle-elements-by-chemical-materials?noredirect=1#comment1337999_520652), which is off topic, so tried to ask here, the question text is:

```
     ---------------
```

I have one tea maker and trying to replace its 220v 2200w element like this:

[image]

So i have another kettle and think that its element, have connected by some chemical adhesive based of this photo:

[image]

But i don't see any, google link for replacing it.

So if it is not welded and fixed on it place by some chemical adhesive it could be unattached by using some anti chemical adhesive materials!

Update:

I googled some terms and found that there is some epoxy glue materials for metal attaching based of [this](https://gluefaq.com/best-heat-resistant-glue/) .

So if that element is connected to the base by epoxy glue, needs some anti epoxy glue to remove it.

So i would appreciate, if you have some experience or detaching this kind of its, or ...

Thanks.

Comment: You may find insights from a search on how to dissolve epoxy glue.

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with fiberglass the go-to for hardened resin was methyl chloride.

There is a wide variety of epoxies.  I don't know if they are similar enough to be dissolved by the same solvent.

Remember too, that attacking this from the edge, you are in essence trying to dissolve something several inches thick, and are doing so in a space small enough that getting the solvent to circulate next to the exposed edge of the adhesive is going to be difficult.  (It may be only a few thousandths of an inch thick.

Also:  I would think that a glued process would slow down production.  What do you do with the base while the glue is setting.

How certain are you that it is an organic adhesive?  Other options:  Silicate based adhesives, low temperature brazing/soldering systems.

While I applaud your frugality and inventiveness trying to repair this item, it really is a disposable consumer item not meant for repair.

Comment: Thanks for you answer,i will consider your answer, and ...